# Difficulty with computing a limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I meet some difficulties when trying to compute this limit,

```
Limit[1/n*Integrate[1/(Cos[x]^2 + 4 Sin[2 x] + 4), {x, 0, Pi*n}],   n -> Infinity,Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]
```

The output is,

```
Limit::cas: Warning: Contradictory assumption(s) (n\[Element]Integers&&(Re[n]<=1/2||n\[NotElement]Reals))&&n>4096 encountered. >>
```

The limit is finite though.

Comment: I'm on version 9.0.1 and I don't need to take the limit :`Simplify[1/n*Integrate[1/(Cos[x]^2 + 4 Sin[2 x] + 4), {x, 0, Pi*n}], 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]` is zero.

Comment: @b.gatessucks it cannot be $0$.

Comment: For $n=1, 2, 3,...$ Mathematica yields $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}$. Could you confirm if it so? I also need to check my work and see why I initially got a different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it up:

```
int = Assuming[Element[n, Integers],
          Integrate[1/(Cos[x]^2 + 4 Sin[2 x] + 4), {x, 0, Pi*n}]]
(*  (n*Pi)/2  *)
```

now

```
Limit[1/n*int, n -> Infinity]
(* Pi/2 *)
```

You do not even need limit.

```
(1/n)*int

(*  Pi/2 *)
```

To do it as you did, you need to put the `Assuming` first, so it *covers* the integral part, like this

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers], 
 Limit[1/n*Integrate[1/(Cos[x]^2 + 4 Sin[2 x] + 4), {x, 0, Pi*n}],n -> Infinity]]

(* Pi/2  *)
```

What you had is this:

```
Limit[1/n*Integrate[1/(Cos[x]^2 + 4 Sin[2 x] + 4), {x, 0, Pi*n}],   
      n -> Infinity,Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]
```

So, the `Integrate` part never knew that `n` was an integer ! This is important. Since without this information, integrate will generate an answer this like this:

```
int = Integrate[1/(Cos[x]^2 + 4 Sin[2 x] + 4), {x, 0, Pi*n}]
(* 1/2 (-ArcTan[2] + ArcTan[2 (1 + Tan[n Pi])]) *)

Assuming[Element[n, Integers], Limit[1/n*int, n -> Infinity]]
(* 0 *)
```

Compare the result on `Integrate` when it *sees* the assumption on `n` being integer:

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers], Integrate[1/(Cos[x]^2 + 4 Sin[2 x] + 4), {x, 0, Pi*n}]]
(* (n Pi)/2  *)
```

big difference

```
1/2 (-ArcTan[2] + ArcTan[2 (1 + Tan[n Pi])])
```

vs

```
(n Pi)/2
```

Comment: Nasser, thanks! (+1) I'm still a bit confused. If we firstly consider the indefinite integral and then take the limits, we get (for $n=1$) Limit[(1/2) ArcTan[2 Sec[x] (Cos[x] + Sin[x])], x -> 0] and Limit[(1/2) ArcTan[2 Sec[x] (Cos[x] + Sin[x])], x -> Pi] both evaluate ArcTan[2]/2. Thus, the value should be $0$.

Comment: In the message above I only considered the case $n=1$. As you also noticed, for all $n$ the values should be the same,i.e. $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: From your first line we know that int = Assuming[Element[n, Integers],
          Integrate[1/(Cos[x]^2 + 4 Sin[2 x] + 4), {x, 0, Pi*n}]]
(*  (n*Pi)/2  *). This means that if we set $n=1$, then the integral from $0$ to $\pi$ is $\pi/2$. If you firstly compute the indefinite integral, and then compute the integration limits you get to the conclusion the integral evaluates $0$.

Comment: That is Integrate[1/(Cos[x]^2 + 4 Sin[2 x] + 4), x] = 1/2 ArcTan[2 Sec[x] (Cos[x] + Sin[x])]. Now, Limit[(1/2) ArcTan[2 Sec[x] (Cos[x] + Sin[x])], x -> Pi]= ArcTan[2]/2 and Limit[(1/2) ArcTan[2 Sec[x] (Cos[x] + Sin[x])], x -> 0]= ArcTan[2]/2. This leads us to the fact that Integrate[1/(Cos[x]^2 + 4 Sin[2 x] + 4), {x, 0, Pi}]]=0 that contradicts the fact that the integral should evaluate $\pi/2$.